# Debian 3.0 eth1 and eth0 switching at boot

Tags: linux, debian

I have a debian 3.0 woody installation. I have eth1 and eth0 being randomly switched at reboot. I cannot figure out how to set a manual way to make this always associate to that network card. It is essentially switching network cards at boot which causes a lot of problems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of the methods suggested here:
http://www.science.uva.nl/research/air/wiki/LogicalInterfaceNames

The most natural one (using udev) is probably not available on a woody system.